# Is it Backbiting (Gheybah)

Tags: nikah, talaq, friendship, adultery, backbiting

My marital relationship has been broken up for my wife's illicit relationship with someone else. When any of my friends or known person ask about the reason, why the relationship has been broken. Is it okay to mention my wife's bad deeds when she is not present obviously. Or it is considered as Backbiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ أَيُّوبَ، وَقُتَيْبَةُ، وَابْنُ، حُجْرٍ قَالُوا حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ، عَنِ الْعَلاَءِ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏‏ أَتَدْرُونَ مَا الْغِيبَةُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالُوا اللَّهُ وَرَسُولُهُ أَعْلَمُ ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ ذِكْرُكَ أَخَاكَ بِمَا يَكْرَهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قِيلَ أَفَرَأَيْتَ إِنْ كَانَ فِي أَخِي مَا أَقُولُ قَالَ ‏"‏ إِنْ كَانَ فِيهِ مَا تَقُولُ فَقَدِ اغْتَبْتَهُ وَإِنْ لَمْ يَكُنْ فِيهِ فَقَدْ بَهَتَّهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏"

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:

Do you know what is backbiting? They (the Companions) said: Allah and His Messenger know best. Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: Backbiting implies your talking about your brother in a manner which he does not like. It was said to him: What is your opinion about this that if I actually find (that failing) in my brother which I made a mention of? He said: If (that failing) is actually found (in him) what you assert, you in fact backbited him, and if that is not in him it is a slander.

Sahih Muslim 2589
In-book : Book 45, Hadith 91
USC-MSA web (English) : Book 32, Hadith 6265  (deprecated)
Sahih Muslim
Just tell only that she leave you coz she loves someone else..dont insult her character or tell her shortcomings...(May Allah blessed you with best spouse and grant u patience)